# Connect sim800 to Raspberry PI (RX, TX)

Tags: python, raspbian

I've been trying to connect my sim800L to my Raspberry pi 3 model B (rasbian) but without success...

I'm at the very first step, and since I'm new to Raspberry pi, I don't understand very well how it works.

Here is how I'm trying to connect it:

[image: montage]

After some research, I've found that I needed to add some things to the `/boot/config.txt` file in order to enable the UART, so I've added this :

```
core_freq=250
enable_uart
```

After, I found out a code that matched what I'm trying to do, here it is:

```
import serial   
import os, time

# Enable Serial Communication
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

# Transmitting AT Commands to the Modem
# '\r\n' indicates the Enter key

port.write('AT'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.read(10)
print rcv
```

But nothing is working in the Python Shell, when I try the AT command, which is supposed to answer OK if the sim800L is successfully connected. I'm getting some basic errors, like AT is not defined.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: you should ask your question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes thanks, and thanks darthbith for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi can not communicate via TXD or RXD if the GND on the SIM card is not connected to the raspberry pi's GND gpio pin.